# How to get the managed metadata fields from site page values via rest api on spfx vue js

Tags: vue.js, spfx

How to fetch the Managed metadata types values using API's in spfx on Vue js? How can I get the actual values using API on

```
/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('" + site page+"')/items?
```

MMS fields unable to fetch ?

Comment: What exactly is your problem? Making REST calls with Vue? Or the response of the Sharepoint API?

Comment: response of the API, to get the Metadata fields via API and enable the filter using the managed metadata fields on API

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pleace tring to get the Managed metadata fields of listitems:

```
_api/web/lists/getbytitle('testlist')/items?$select=ID,Title,MetaField,TaxCatchAll/ID,TaxCatchAll/Term&$expand=TaxCatchAll
```

The page properties include manage metadata fields:

```
/_api/web/getFolderByServerRelativeUrl('page')?$expand=Folders,Files/ListItemAllFields"
```

Refer:[get-all-sharepoint-document-library-files](https://sympmarc.com/2016/04/23/get-all-sharepoint-document-library-files-and-folders-at-a-serverrelativeurl-in-one-rest-call/)